# Validate at least one field to be filled in, Gravity forms

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, validation, gravity-forms-plugin

I have been trying to create a custom validation hook for Gravity Forms plugin.

The validation checks that at least one field has been filled in from a set of fields.

Check out the code below, I just can't get it too work. I think it is something to do with the variables for the inputs, even if a field is filled in, the error still shows on each field?

```
add_filter( 'gform_field_validation_2', function ( $result, $value, $form, $field ) {

    if ( $field->type == 'number') {

        $a = rgar( $value, $field->id . '10' );
        $b = rgar( $value, $field->id . '12' );
        $c = rgar( $value, $field->id . '13' );
        $d = rgar( $value, $field->id . '14' );
        $e = rgar( $value, $field->id . '15' );
        $f = rgar( $value, $field->id . '17' );
        $g = rgar( $value, $field->id . '18' );
        $h = rgar( $value, $field->id . '20' );
        $i = rgar( $value, $field->id . '21' );
        $j = rgar( $value, $field->id . '22' );
        $k = rgar( $value, $field->id . '23' );


        if ( !empty($a) || !empty($b) || !empty($c) || !empty($d) || !empty($e) || !empty($f) || !empty($g) || !empty($h) || !empty($i) || !empty($j) || !empty($k) ) {
          $result['is_valid'] = true;
          $result['message'] ='';
        } else {
          $result['is_valid'] = false;
          $result['message']  = 'Please select a quantity of materials to order';
        }

    }

    return $result;
}, 10, 4 );
```

Comment: what type of field are you trying to validate?

Comment: Its a number field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So heres a working version (Thanks for the gform_validation hint Francisco R) - Went down a slightly different route, but works perfectly, incase anyone interested in future!

```
add_filter( 'gform_validation_2', 'custom_validation_2' );
function custom_validation_2( $validation_result ) {

    // array of field IDs to be checked
    $field_ids = array (10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18, 20, 21, 23, 22);

    // get the form object from the validation result
    $form = $validation_result['form'];

    // counter to store how many fields have a value > 0 submitted
    $number_of_fields = 0;

    // loop through all the fields to be sure one has a value > 0
    foreach ( $field_ids as $input ) {
        // the rgpost string we are going to check
        $input_id = 'input_' . intval( $input );

        // the value that was submitted
        $input_value = rgpost ( $input_id );

        if ( $input_value > 0 ) {
            // if any field in the array has a value, we can just continue
            $number_of_fields++;
        } // end if
        else {
            // no value for this input, so continue without incrementing the counter
            continue;
        } // end else

    } // end foreach

    // check the $number_of_fields and if it is 0 return a validation error
    if ( $number_of_fields == 0 ){

        // set the form validation to false
        $validation_result['is_valid'] = false;

        // mark all the fields with a validation error
        foreach( $form['fields'] as &$field ) {

            // add a validation error to *all* the inputs if none were submitted > 0
            if ( in_array( $field->id, $field_ids ) ) {
                $field->failed_validation = true;
                $field->validation_message = 'Please select a quantity of materials to order from one or all of these fields.';
            } // end if
        } // end foreach

    } // end if

    // assign modified $form object back to the validation result
    $validation_result['form'] = $form;
    return $validation_result;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you maybe should use a field of type "radio buttons".

Anyway, if your form has several "number" fields and you need to validate that at least one of them has been filled, then you should use the `gform_validation` filter since you're validating the whole form, not just a single field.

TIP: Add a custom css class to each field in the group to identify them. for example "validate-quantity".

```
add_filter('gform_validation_2', 'quantity_validation', 1, 4);
function quantity_validation($validation_result) {
    if ($validation_result['is_valid']) {
        $valid=false;
        $form = $validation_result['form'];
        foreach( $form['fields'] as &$field ) {
            if ( strpos( $field->cssClass, 'validate-quantity' ) === false ) {
                continue;
            }
            $field_value = rgpost( "input_{$field['id']}" );
            if (!empty($field_value)) {
               $valid=true;
               break;
            }
        }

        if (!$valid) {
            $field["failed_validation"] = true;
            $field["validation_message"] = 'Please select a quantity of materials to order';
            $validation_result['form'] = $form;
        }

    }
    return $validation_result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks you should change your if clause to:

```
if ( empty($a) || empty($b) || empty($c) || empty($d) || empty($e) || empty($f) || empty($g) || empty($h) || empty($i) || empty($j) || empty($k) ) {
```

to validate if at least one option is selected.

To skip not targeted fields add the following code before complex if above:

```
$target_fields = array('name_1', 'name_2');
if (!in_array($field, $target_fields)) {
    $result['is_valid'] = true;
    $result['message']  = '';
}
```

Comment: Won't that prove false as it will be making sure they all have a value?
Also upon trying that I am still getting the initial issue of the error effecting all fields even those not targeted